# How to make rounded rectangle in circle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, google-material-design, graphic-styles

Here i m working on meteor like design but i have hard time making those rounded design in planet
[image: My design]

[image: How to get those shapes in my planet design]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illustrator: Clipping Mask Struggles](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71889/illustrator-clipping-mask-struggles)

Answer (score 2):

In my way doing, i took series of lines(alternate green & blue) with stroke around 6pt on top of a Rectangle box(red).

Next selected Blue lines (changed to expand both lines)...

While both lines(Blue colour one) + box selcted...click on Minus in pathfinder.

Tht's it now change the red color to green :) :) Now you can insert this strecture into any Round circles :).

Hopw it helps you.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]